# Monitor goes blank after 30 minutes. No keyboard or mouse are attatched, but computer is controlled over SSH

Tags: ssh, suspend, monitor, xserver

Currently trying to set up a media server which I can control with my laptop or phone. After looking at all the options I decided upon using SSH to start mplayer in fullscreen. Everything is working fine. Until 30 minutes in when the monitor suspends. I can make the monitor wake up from suspension with the xset -dpms, but the screen stays black, until I plug in a peripheral and do some for of input.

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like Power Management Preferences. (Ubuntu 10.04)
When I choose **System --> Preferences--> Power Management** *the default for Monitor Standby is 30 minutes*. The options are ranging from **1 minute to NEVER**

ALSO, check your **Screensaver Settings** There is a check box where you can choose to "Activate Screen Saver when computer is idle." (Uncheck this box.)
The default screensaver is "Blank" (Blank screen)
~ Hope this helps.